# Get all unique values for each different column values

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

1.**Input:** we have a dataframe

```
ID name
1   a
1   b
1   a
2   c
3   d
```

2.Now I want to get all the unique 'name' values for each 'ID' values **Expected Result:**

```
ID name
1   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
```

Code I tried is half working to get only the first value for name, but I also want it for each ID:

```
df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first', subset=['name'])]
```

How should my code change as per my need ?

Comment: You can filter the duplicates on both `ID` and `name` if that is what you need i.e. by using `subset=['ID', 'name']`. And, if your dataframe has only these two columns, not specifyin `subset` will also have same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset='name', keep="last")
```

or

```py
df.sort_values('name', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('ID').sort_index()
```

To drop duplicates based on multiple columns:

```py
df = df.drop_duplicates(['col_name1','col_name2','col_name3'], keep='last')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a simple `groupby` as well -

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = {'ID':[1,1,1,2,3],'name':['a','b','a','c','d']}
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> 
>>> df.groupby(['ID','name']).size().reset_index().drop(columns={0})
   ID name
0   1    a
1   1    b
2   2    c
3   3    d
```